# onSubmit handler not working and I can't submit/validate my Formik form in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik, yup, onsubmit

I am a beginner to Formik forms and Yup Validation, However I am working on this form and I am not able to make the form submit successfully. I will appreciate your help what's going wrong in my code and why it's not submitting ?

my Yup validation (might not be the problem)

```
const validate = Yup.object({
    name: Yup.string()
             .max(20, "Must be 20 characters or less" )
             .required('required'),
    school: Yup.string("required name").required('Please select your school').oneOf(schools),
    jobType: Yup.string().required("are you a student or a staff member ?!"),
    parentName: Yup.string().required("enter parent name"),
    parentPhone: Yup.number().required("Enter phone number"),
    parentEmail: Yup.string().email().required("enter parent Email"),
    staffPhone: Yup.string().required("enter staff Phone number"),
    staffEmail: Yup.string().email().required("enter staff Email"),
    condition: Yup.string().required("Please chose one").oneOf(condition)
    
    
})
```

My formik tag, the only thing in the return statement

```
<Formik
        initialValues ={{
            name: '',
            school: '',
            jobType: '',
            // isStudent:'student',
            // isStaffMember:'staffMember',
            parentName: "",
            parentPhone: '',
            parentEmail: '',
            staffPhone:'',
            staffEmail: '',
            condition:'',
            ...signupVals
        }}
       
        onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Logging in", setSubmitting);
            setSubmitting(false);
          }, 500);
        }}
        
        validationSchema={validate}
        // onSubmit={async (values) => {
        //   await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500));
        //   Window.alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        // }}
    
    >
      {({values, errors, touched, isValidating, isSubmitting}) => (
     
      <>
      {console.log(values)}
       {console.log("submit ", isSubmitting)}
       {console.log("validate ", isValidating)}
        <div>
          <h1 className=" my-4 font-weight-bold-display-4">
              Sign Up
          </h1>
    <Form >
            <div className='my-4'>
                <label className="form-label"  >Name: </label>
            
                <Field  className="ms-2" label ="name" name="name" type="text"  id="exampleFormControlInput1" />
                <ErrorMessage name="name" component='inline-block' style={{color:"red" , fontSize:"12px"}} />
                {/* {errors} */}

            </div>
            <div className='my-4'>
                <label>School: </label>
                <Field  className="ms-2"  label ="school" as="select" name="school" >
                      <option />
                      <option>Aim Academy</option>
                      <option>Beyond Academy</option>
                      <option>Curiousity Academy</option>
                      <option>Discover Academy</option>
                      <option>Explore Academy</option>
                </Field>
                <ErrorMessage name="school" component='inline-block' style={{color:"red" , fontSize:"12px"}} />
            </div>
            
            <div id="my-radio-group" className='my-4'>Job type</div>
            <ErrorMessage name="jobType" component='inline-block' style={{color:"red" , fontSize:"12px"}} />

              <div role="group" aria-labelledby="my-radio-group" >
                <div className='my-4'>
                <label >
                <Field  className="px-2" type="radio" name="jobType" value="student"  onClick={handleIsStudent}/>
                Student
                </label>
              
                </div>



                <div className='my-4'>

                <label>
                <Field type="radio" name="jobType" value="staff member"   onClick={handleIsStaff} />
                Staff member</label> 
                </div>
              
                {isStudent ?<>
                <label > Parent name
                  <Field className=" my-3 ms-2" type="input" name="parentName" />
                  <ErrorMessage name="parentName"  component='inline-block' style={{color:"red" , fontSize:"12px"}}/>

                  </label>
                <label> Parent Phone
                  <Field  className=" my-3 ms-2" type="input" name="parentPhone" />
                  <ErrorMessage name="parentPhone" component='inline-block' style={{color:"red" , fontSize:"12px"}} />

                  </label>
                <label> Parent Email
                  <Field   className=" my-3 ms-2" type="input" name="parentEmail" />
                  <ErrorMessage name="parentEmail" component='inline-block' style={{color:"red" , fontSize:"12px"}} />

                  </label>
                  </>: null}



                  {isStaff ?<>
                <label> staff phone
                  <Field  className=" my-3 ms-2" type="input" name="staffPhone" />
                  <ErrorMessage name="staffPhone" component='inline-block' style={{color:"red" , fontSize:"12px"}} />

                  </label>
                <label> staff Email
                  <Field   className=" my-3 ms-2" type="input" name="staffEmail" />
                  <ErrorMessage name="staffEmail"  component='inline-block' style={{color:"red" , fontSize:"12px"}}/>

                  
                  </label>
               
                  </>: null}



   
                  <div className='my-4'>
                <label>Condition: </label>
                <Field  className="ms-2"  label ="Condition" as="select" name="condition" >
                      <option />
                      <option>Experiencing Symptoms</option>
                      <option>Tested positive for Covid</option>
                      
                </Field>
                <ErrorMessage name="condition" component='inline-block' style={{color:"red" , fontSize:"12px"}} />
            </div>
            
        </div> 
            <button className="btn btn-dark mt-3" type="submit"  > Register</button>
            <button className="btn btn-danger mt-3 ml-3" type="submit" > Reset</button>
            {/* {console.log(values)} */}
            <TextField {...values} />

        </Form>
</div>
</>
 )}
   
    </Formik>
```

To my understanding wrapping the  inside  will allow the form to fire automatically the onSubmit handler function I have! but I am not sure and would appreciate your help to figure this out?!

Comment: Hi. Can you comment out the setTimeout and log out the value in `onSubmit`?

Comment: sure, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good practice to submit your form every 500ms. With that said, I'll suggest moving the form into it's own component and using `useFormikContext` move the autosubmit into an `useEffect`:

1. Refactor to follow this structure:

```
<Formik ...>
 <NewComponent/>
</Formik>
```

2. In the `NewComponent` paste all the field of your form
3. In the `NewComponent` get the context of `values` and `handleSubmit`:

```
  const { values, handleSubmit } = useFormikContext();
```

4. Also in the `NewComponent` add a new `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    handleSubmit();
  }, [values]);
```

That will give you an auto-submit, every time the users modify something in the fields. You can easily add the 500ms submit here too!

Here's the example:

[image: Edit prod-grass-fmyxyy]

Comment: thank you very much, just saw that however the link in code sandbox does not work. it loaded the first time only. 
and I would truly appreciate if you can explain to me how to hide some of the fields at first. I am trying to show the fields related to students or staff member based on user's choice. was trying to use the when method but it's not working, not sure if you can help with that as well

Comment: Also, quick update. Form is submittable now, However my main issue is with the Yup validation as I am trying to find a way to use both when() and required at the same time but it's clunky and the form will submit even if we are missing some rewquired values or even worse, It does not detect that you have met the criteria for field validation, so I would check the radio button and submit the form and I will find the value inside console.log but still screen is showing me error message on the screen.

Comment: Yeah in the CodeSandbox, I omitted some of the hooks (useState) you have originally. Those will still be needed to hide/show the fields. 
If the form is submitting with required fields in the validation, the problem may be that it's not validating the right fields. Double check that the `name` of the field is exactly the same in the validationSchema.

Comment: I've updated the  [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-grass-fmyxyy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/App.js). 
It has some validation using `when()` depending on the jobType.